# Selenium Webdriver-python, unable to find the dynamic element, tried all the possible ways

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am successfully able to navigate to the desired page after logging in. Static elements are located and printed, peacefully. The page makes JavaScript call and the contents are updated after about 4-5 seconds, I'm unable to locate the dynamic elements.

I'm attaching the image of Inspect element before and after loading of Javascript elements.

Please, have a look at the code below and suggest the possible solution.
P.S. Out of 100 times this worked worked for about 2-3 times.

```
layer = "https://desired.website"
driver.get(layer)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys('my@email.com')
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys('myPassword')
driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-173kae7").click()

#NOW I'M SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN
#Opening the Desired Page, This is a static element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-1nga9gi")))
driver.execute_script('''window.open("desired.page","_blank");''')

#Successfully opened desired page and switched to newly opened tab
#Trying to access the element present in <tbody> tag, please refer "Inspect Element after JavaScript elements are loaded"- image.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-167dqxg")))
check = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ccss-13ozsj7")
for e in check:
    print(e.text)
print("ALL DATA SUCCESSFULLY PRINTED")
```

Nothing happens for 30 seconds and I get time-out error and "ALL DATA SUCCESSFULY PRINTED" is displayed.

ERROR CODE I GET IS:

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-167dqxg")))
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Please have a look at the Inspect element.

[Inspect Element at the beginning of Page Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHZ3Q.png)

[Inspect Element after JavaScript elements are loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bpW.png)

Comment: I can't really see any obvious problems with your code, you may wish to inspect the page source that selemium sees with page_source() to validate that it can even see it.

Comment: Page source returns simple HTML content without any useful data as the page is JS Rendered. Can't seem to find, what's wrong with this code or website.

Is there any alternate way to scrape data, which contains logging in facility with navigation in the website?

Comment: Hmmm is the tag you're trying to locate in the page source output?  Are you running headless? When selenium runs can you see the elements you're trying to locate with it?  I've seen cases where some code doesn't play well with phantomjs, but will work fine in chrome.

Comment: You may be having trouble with switching to the new content of the new ***tab***, how are you switching to the new tab?

Comment: @Sourav Update the question with the text based _HTML_ for the element `(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-167dqxg")`

Comment: UPDATE:  Code seems to work pretty fine and Scrape the useful data when I minimize the browser as it opens, If I let the browser opened as it is, the code throws an Timeout Exception. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be switching to the new content on the tab opened, please try to add this:

```
#after this line
driver.execute_script('''window.open("desired.page","_blank");''')
#try adding this
#this will switch to the newest tab
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

You may be stuck looking for your desired ***elements*** on the old tab.

Answer (score 0):

when using Python use either 'starts-with' instead of 'undefined-object'

## EMAIL ADDRESS XPATH .//*[@id='email-undefined-objectObject-26149']

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[starts-with(@id,'email')]".clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[starts-with(@id,'email')]".send_keys("scotty.mitch@gmail.com"))
....or 'contains'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'email')]".clear()